# Cannot trim closed bracket from vb.net string

Tags: vb.net

I have an issue trimming a string in vb.net

```
Dim bgColor1 As String = (foundRows(count).Item(16).ToString()) 

'This returns Color [Indigo] I need it to be just Indigo so vb.net can read it.

'So i used this

Dim MyChar() As Char = {"C", "o", "l", "r", "[", "]", " "}
Dim firstBgcolorbgColor1 As String = bgColor1.TrimStart(MyChar)

'But the ] is still in the string so it looks like this Indigo]
```

Any ideas on why i cannot trim the ]?

Comment: ...and what happens when `Color [Cyan]` gets returned?  The "C" is going to get trimmed from the start.  You're better off actually looking for the square brackets and retrieving what is in-between them.

Comment: Will there always be only **one** set of brackets in the input?  Will it always start with "Color ["?...so many different ways you could extract that value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Didn't see that the input was "Color [Indigo]".  I would not recommend `TrimStart()` & `TrimEnd()`

You have a variety of options to choose from:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim Color As String = "Color [Indigo]"

        ' Substring() & IndexOf()
        Dim openBracket = Color.IndexOf("[") + 1
        Dim closeBracket = Color.IndexOf("]")
        Console.WriteLine(Color.Substring(openBracket, closeBracket - openBracket))

        ' Replace()
        Console.WriteLine(Color.Replace("Color [", String.Empty).Replace("]", String.Empty))

        ' Regex.Replace()
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Color, "Color \[|\]", String.Empty))

        ' Regex.Match()
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(Color, "\[(\w+)\]").Groups(1)) 
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
Indigo
Indigo
Indigo
Indigo
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Izqndr)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are calling `TrimStart(...)`, which as the name implies, will only trim the front part of the string.

Did you mean to call `Trim(MyChar)` instead?

Comment: No i want to use trim start because Trim cuts the "o" off the end of Indigo
</br>
So i just added a TrimEnd(Mychar2) and added ] to MyChar2() so it looks like this now, Thanks for the idea.</br>

    `Dim MyChar() As Char = {"C", "o", "l", "r", "[", "]", " "} </br>
    Dim firstBgcolorbgColor1 As String = bgColor1.TrimStart(MyChar)</br>
    Dim MyChar2() As Char = {"]"}</br>
    Dim secondColorbgColor1 As String = firstBgcolorbgColor1.TrimEnd(MyChar2)`</br>

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Regex to do the job:

```
Dim colorRegex As New Regex("(?<=\[)\w+") 'Get the word following the bracket ([)

Dim firstBgcolorbgColor1 As String = colorRegex.Match(bgColor1).Value
```

Answer (score -1):

The `TrimStart`, `TrimEnd`, and `Trim` functions remove spaces from beginning, end and both side of the strings respectively. You are using `TrimStart` to remove any leading the spaces but it is leaving white space is at the end. So you need to use `Trim`. Trim won't remove anything else than white space characters, so your `]` character will still appear in the final string. You need to do String.Remove to remove characters you don't want.

Examples here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-vbnet

Comment: "Trim won't remove anything else than white space characters".  Correct...but only if you don't pass in anything.  There's an overload for all the [Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) functions that allow you to pass in an array of characters to remove...and this is what he's using.